MacOSでPythonのturtle機能を使って図を描きたいが、何にも表示されない
Pythonのturtle機能を使って図を書くつもりだったけど、python turtle graphicsが真白になった。
そして以下のようなエラーが出ている。どうやって以下のコードをうまく運行させますか？
表示されたメッセージ:
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
2024-07-14 01:04:21.104 Python[3335:59697] WARNING: Secure coding is automatically enabled for restorable state! However, not on all supported macOS versions of this application. Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:.

現状のコード:
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()

pen.pencolor("red")
pen.forward(100)
turtle.done()

実行結果:


OSのバージョンは何ですか？Pythonのバージョンは何ですか？

最終更新が古い記事ですが原因はこれかも。IDLE and tkinter with Tcl/Tk on macOS それから英語サイトで関連すると思われる記事。Getting "DEPRECATION WARNING" about Tk, DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated, M1 Mac in Vs Code - global Python [duplicate]
